# which broadcast receiver does execute first: dynamic or static?

Tags: android, arcore

While working with Android, I have one broadcast receiver which registers dynamically as well as statically. So my question is which has max priority to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the priority set for particular BroadcastReceiver:

- If the priority is not set, the receivers will be executed in an arbitrary order.
- If the priority is set to the receiver either by using

  `<intent-filter android:priority="999">` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

  **OR**

  `filter.setPriority(999);` when registered through code.

  Receiver with higher priority will be executed first.

Comment: If both the priority same then?

Comment: @BorkarPratik they will be executed in an arbitrary order